# Replace all path on image file name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of image in a page.

```
 <img src="image/one.jpg"/>
 <img src="image/two.jpg"/>
 <img src="image/three.jpg"/>
 <img src="image/four.jpg"/>
 <img src="image/five.jpg"/>
 <img src="image/six.jpg"/>
 <img src="image/seven.jpg"/>
```

How to change the path of `image/` into `'http://mywebsite.com/folder/'` when the first time the page is load?

I want to use javascript, or jquery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code and what you tried, and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Try googling "loop over HTML elements using jquery" if you need a place to start.

Comment: At the time theDOMready event fires, a browser might already have tried to access the old source attribute. If possible, try to store the path info within a custom data attribute so a browser is not tempted to load the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i think you need to define an identifier, like a ID or Class, then you can use this code:

In this code we change the path of all elements of "classX" class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.classX').each(function() {
        var path = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', path.replace("image", "http://mywebsite.com/folder"));
    })
})
```

Comment: The problem is I got this content of html is from another server with curl in php. When I tried this, it replace all the path, but the image name is not stay there, the image name is gone too

Comment: Are you sure that code changes all the path? It doesnt make sense.

Comment: It didn''t when I add class name to the tag. If I don't add class name, it changes all the path.

Comment: I don't know how it happens, can you please share the code or any screenshot?

Comment: all the img tags + its srcs are I got from another website with jsp extension. The problem is this img tags do not have a class or id.  If I use your code like this ` $('img').each(function()`, it will remove all the path of the src in the img tag. So, I tried to addClass first, and then your code works.

Comment: Is so strange a img tag without identifier. Hehe

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method

```
$('img').attr('src','http://mywebsite.com/folder/');
```

Comment: The problem is I got this content of html is from another server with curl in php. When I tried this, it replace all the path, but the image name is not stay there, the image name is gone too

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using `.each()` to loop over img elements and then use `substring()` method to get the src of each img tag:

```
$("img").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("src","http://mywebsite.com/folder/"+($(this).attr("src")).substring(($(this).attr("src")).lastIndexOf("/")+1));
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/39k8dg43/)

Comment: The problem is I got this content of html is from another server with curl in php. When I tried this, it replace all the path, but the image name is not stay there, the image name is gone too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .attr() on dom ready

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('img').attr('src', function (i, src) {
        return 'http://mywebsite.com/folder/' + src.split('/')[1];
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ak3y69ga/)

Comment: The problem is I got this content of html is from another server with curl in php. When I tried this, it replace all the path, but the image name is not stay there, the image name is gone too